# IF/ELSE inside FOR LOOP

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to implement an IF/ELSE statement inside a FOR-LOOP which will go over all column names for a specific table belonging to a given owner, when this matches a provided condition. However, how would I just return this value?

I am thinking about it in python syntax:

```
for val in table:
  if val == 'BRAND':
    return val
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
DECLARE
  vstmt VARCHAR2(4000);
  vresult VARCHAR2(4000);
  vcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
FOR VAL IN (
SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns where owner like '%USER%' and table_name like '%TEST%')
LOOP
vstmt := 'IF VAL == "BRAND" '
```

Unsure of the syntax to return `VAL` in the `THEN` statement (still new to SQL.)

Here is a simpler example because I obviously do not know what I am doing in the above query:

```
BEGIN
FOR VAL IN (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns where owner like '%USER%' and table_name like '%TEST%')
LOOP
IF (VAL like '%BRAND') 
THEN dbms_output.put_line(VAL);
ELSE dbms_output.put_line('No Matches Found');
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Returns this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'LIKE'
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Which flavour of SQL is this? Always tag your DBMS as well (as per the [tag:sql] tag description)

Comment: What are you trying to implement?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @jarlh I essentially wanted to iterate over all values from the first column_name query and when a column_name value matches `BRAND` then return only this, otherwise throw something like `Not found`.

Comment: Use a case expression in the SELECT clause to get brand/not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```sql
DECLARE
  found BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  FOR VAL IN (
    SELECT column_name
    FROM   all_tab_columns
    WHERE  owner      LIKE '%USER%'
    AND    table_name LIKE '%TEST%'
  )
  LOOP
    IF (VAL.column_name LIKE '%BRAND%') 
    THEN
      found := TRUE;
      dbms_output.put_line(VAL.column_name);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  IF NOT found THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('No Matches Found');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

or:

```sql
DECLARE
  found BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  FOR VAL IN (
    SELECT column_name
    FROM   all_tab_columns
    WHERE  owner       LIKE '%USER%'
    AND    table_name  LIKE '%TEST%'
    AND    column_name LIKE '%BRAND%'
  )
  LOOP
    found := TRUE;
    dbms_output.put_line(VAL.column_name);
  END LOOP;
  IF NOT found THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('No Matches Found');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

But there does not appear to be a reason to use PL/SQL when you could simply use SQL:

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM   all_tab_columns
WHERE  owner LIKE '%USER%'
AND    table_name LIKE '%TEST%'
AND    column_name LIKE '%BRAND%';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bq62YeyB)

Comment: Very helpful explanation! The first example was exactly the aim I expected and had in mind to achieve. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear (at least, to me) what final result you want, but - here's an example which might get you started.

It loops through tables (whose name contains "DEP") in my schema (why not `all_tab_columns` You restricted owner to `USER`, and that's currently logged user so - why not using `user_tab_columns` instead?), scanning all columns for string "Sales":

- if it is found, number of occurrences is displayed
- if not, it says so
- if there's an error (for example, because you're searching NUMBER datatype columns for a string), it is also displayed

Can it be improved? Certainly, only if we know what you wanted.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select table_name, column_name
  6                  from user_tab_columns
  7                  where table_name like '%DEP%'
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      begin
 11        l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 12                 '  where ' || cur_r.column_name || q'[ = 'Sales']';
 13        execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 14
 15        if l_cnt > 0 then
 16           dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name ||': '|| l_cnt);
 17        else
 18           dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name ||': Not found');
 19        end if;
 20      exception
 21        when others then
 22          dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name ||': Not found due to ' || sqlerrm);
 23      end;
 24    end loop;
 25  end;
 26  /
DEPARTMENT.DEPT_NO: Not found
DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID: Not found due to ORA-01722: invalid number
DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME: 1
DEPT.DEPTNO: Not found due to ORA-01722: invalid number
DEPT.DNAME: Not found
DEPT.LOC: Not found
NEW_DEPT.DEPTNO: Not found due to ORA-01722: invalid number
NEW_DEPT.DNAME: Not found
NEW_DEPT.LOC: Not found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, I have updated my post with an extra query example. I did not know what I was doing with the original query. I hope this explains things better. I actually replaced the original owner for `USER` just in this example, because I was hiding the owner of my table. But I could have replaced it with any string. I will read more into your post. Thank you for your help!

Comment: As I said, code I posted *works* (compiles, returns some result) so I'd suggest you to look at it and modify it if you want to. I don't feel like salvaging your code as it would ultimately lead to code I already posted.

Comment: Right, I see what you have done. I have noticed the general census when working with loops and to identify where a value exists or not is to count its occurrence.